# How can I take data out of a text file line by line, part by part?

Tags: c#, arraylist, text-files, streamreader

So I've been hitting my head against the wall trying to fill this list box with ID numbers saved into a text file. It's simple enough to get the lines out of the file and put them into a list box like that, but that ID number is also shared with more information that I want to display in other text boxes.

**Edit**
So this is a comma delimited file and here is an example of a student's stored information:

> 1234561, Hubert, Huphrey, 123 Apple, Townsville, Some State, MM/DD/YYYY

To put it plainly, I have this text file that has multiple ID #'s, Names, and Addresses, but I just want to display the ID #'s so they can be clicked on from their list box so the rest of the information can be displayed on screen.

I have already taken in a lot of advice, but my thick head can't figure out a few key points. Let me start off by sharing the code I have so far:

**EDIT** I have updated the method to work with the new `Student` Class. But Now I need to figure out how to work with the collection to get the properties of the class.

```
        List<Student> colStudents = new List<Student>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGetStudents_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Define a Student object variable with the name StudentInfo
                string strStudentList;
                // Declare a StreamReader variable for Student Object
                StreamReader srStudent = new StreamReader("StudentData.txt");
                // intIndex is the index of the contact chosen
                int intIndex = lstStudentsID.SelectedIndex;

                //Clear list box to avoid having it fill up too much
                lstStudentsID.Items.Clear();

                // Read the disk file structure
                while (srStudent.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    // Read disk file into a string variable using the ReadLine method.
                    strStudentList = srStudent.ReadLine();
                    // Tokenize the string read from Student object
                    string[] tokenize = strStudentList.Split(',');
                    // Create a student object instance from the Student class.
                    Student StudentInfo = new Student();
                    // Set properties of Student object to array element containing the student data
                    StudentInfo.StudentID = int.Parse(tokenize[0]);
                    StudentInfo.StudentFirstName = tokenize[1];
                    StudentInfo.StudentLastName = tokenize[2];
                    StudentInfo.StudentAddressCity = tokenize[3];
                    StudentInfo.StudnetBirthDate = tokenize[4];
                    // Add student object to collection
                    colStudents.Add(StudentInfo);
                    // Add ID's to the listbox
                    lstStudentsID.Items.Add(StudentInfo.StudentID);
                }
                //Close disk file after all records have been read in
                srStudent.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Experiencing the following disk problems: " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Disk File", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**:
Now that I have the while loop working well enough, I need to either figure out how to utilize the collection or just find a way to use a second and third method to print out the selected student's full name and address

Here's my new class:

```
public class Student
    {
        // Properties
        private double _ID;  // Student's ID, double just in case int is too small
        private string _StudentFirstName;  // Student's Name
        private string _StudentLastName;
        private string _StudentAddressStreet;
        private string _StudentAddressCity;
        private string _StudentBirthDate;

        // Constructor
        public Student()
        {
            _ID = 0;
            _StudentFirstName = "";
            _StudentLastName = "";
            _StudentAddressStreet = "";
            _StudentAddressCity = "";
            _StudentBirthDate = "";
        }

        // ID Property
        public double StudentID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set { _ID = value; }
        }

        // First Name Property
        public string StudentFirstName
        {
            get { return _StudentFirstName; }
            set { _StudentFirstName = value; }
        }

        // Last name Property
        public string StudentLastName
        {
            get { return _StudentLastName; }
            set { _StudentLastName = value; }
        }

        // Address Property
        public string StudentAddressStreet
        {
            get { return _StudentAddressStreet; }
            set { _StudentAddressStreet = value; }
        }

        // Address Property
        public string StudentAddressCity
        {
            get { return _StudentAddressCity; }
            set { _StudentAddressCity = value; }
        }

        // Address Property
        public string StudnetBirthDate
        {
            get { return _StudentBirthDate; }
            set { _StudentBirthDate = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you click the button your program should open and read through the disk file. When a record is read from the disk file you should be creating a student object, updating the properties of the student object and then adding it to the collection (colStudents). It should also add the student ID to the list box control.

When the user clicks a student id in the ListBox control then the student object will be retrieved from the student collection so you can display the student information of the window.

Comment: Where is the `Student` class? A student class with properties of ID, Name and Address appears to be a missing piece.   `public class Student {    public int ID { get; set; }   public string Name { get; set; }    public string Addesss { get; set; }`. Then make a `List<Student>` before reading the text file.. With each `ReadLine`, create a new `Student` object, then add it to the `List<Student>`.  The current code is NOT “saving” any of the data read from the file.

Comment: But of course! I should have known that was what I was missing! So basically I can change my list in the field to work with that class!

Comment: @JohnG So the properties would be the fields within the class, right? Would it be something like this: ```// ID Property
        public double StudentID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set { _ID = value; }
        }
```

Comment: Correct, my last comment shows the code for a simple `Student` class.

Answer (score 0):

You create dictionary with Key as studentid and value as file line
then using dictionary you can populate the  list box
when user select particular list item retrieve the data from dictionary do not perform IO operation.

Dictionary studentInfo = new Dictionary();

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        StreamReader Student = new StreamReader("StudentData.txt");
        // intIndex is the index of the contact chosen
        intIndex = lstStudentsID.SelectedIndex;
        // Add student to colStudents list
        colStudents.Add(Student.ToString());
        // Read the disk file structure
        while (Student.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            // Read disk file into a string variable using the ReadLine method.
            strStudentInfo = Student.ReadLine();
            // Tokenize the string read from Student object
            string[] tokenize = strStudentInfo.Split(',');
            // Create a student object instance from the Student class.
            string temp = tokenize[0];

            studentInfo.Add("Key", strStudentInfo);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TestReadFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String fileName = "StudentData.txt";

        //read file into stream, try-with-resources
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            stream.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```